# Shift Queryset result

Tags: python, django

all. Got a little problem with my Queryset result iwhanna shift it by wayve effect.

```
menus = ShopMenu.objects.filter(shop=shop_id)
```

he is return result for my:

```
1 ---
2 ---
3 ---
4 ---
```

But that's not really what I need. I would like to receive

```
4 ----
1 ---
2 ---
3 ---
```

Haw i can get that result?

Comment: yeap. itry do trhat

Answer (score 0):

You can get last id in aggregate query.

```
from django.db.models import Max
last_id = ShopMenu.objects.aggregate(last_id=Max('id'))['last_id']
```

And then add additional field to your query using [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) and order by this field:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, BooleanField
menus = ShopMenu.objects.annotate(
    show_before=Case(
        When(id=last_id, then=Value(True)), 
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
).order_by('show_before', 'id')
```